# Is it possible to programmatically/off-session charge users without SetupIntent, with only the details got from their first PaymentIntent?

Tags: stripe-payments

We have a website handed over to us that charged the users using the PaymentIntent for the first time.

But
we wish to charge the users agan in the future without them filling up the form again or even if they are offline. So hopefully via API, we can programmatically charge them again.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but if there was no [SetupIntent](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/setup-intents) created on the first payment, we wouldn't be able to charge them again in the future right? even if the website saved the `customer ID`, `paymentIntent ID`, and `paymentMethod ID` from the first payment?

I am still asking/hopeful because of these two things that I noticed:

1. They configured the [setup_future_usage](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-setup_future_usage) to `off_session` but I am not sure if that actually helps in this case?
2. I noticed that even though there was no `SetupIntent` was created, if the user has used credit cards on the payment, we can still charge them again via the Stripe Admin dashboard: [image] This is actually what they currently using to charge again the users. But we want to do it automatically/bulk from our own website/dashboard. I am checking if there's a way we can do this via the API or programmatically from our server?

I hope somebody can help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using Checkout Sessions, then there are two ways to create a PaymentMethod that can be reused:

1. Create a SetupIntent, as explained in the [Stripe doc here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse?platform=web).
2. Create a PaymentIntent with `setup_future_usage` set, as explained in the [Stripe doc here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment). Note that `setup_future_usage` has two possible values: [`on_session` and `off_Session`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-setup_future_usage).

From your description it seems that your implementation is using option 2 with `setup_future_usage=off_session`. So it allows you to charge customers later from the dashboard and with the API.

The documentation covers [how to charge a PaymentMethod off-session with the API](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment?platform=web#charge-saved-payment-method). But to summarize, you’ll need to do something like this (here in Node.js):

```js
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
  // Set the amount and currency
  amount: 1000,
  currency: 'aud',
  
  // Pass the existing PaymentMethod and Customer
  payment_method: 'pm_xxx',
  customer: 'cus_xxx',

  // Tell Stripe to try to automatically confirm the payment
  confirm: true,
  off_session: true,
});
```

Comment: How can i show the saved cards to customer to do a off_session payment?
for an istant payment thanks to payment_sheet i can normally show cards and pay
but with future payment i didn't find solutions

Comment: You can list the PaymentMethod of a specific customer with [this](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/list) and then display them yourself on the frontend.